# Operator norm of difference of tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, operator-theory, tensor-products, unitary-matrices

Let $U$ and $S$ be operators in the projective unitary group $PU(d)$. Additionally, let $\Omega$ be a denumerable subset of the positive integers. If $|| U^{\otimes n}-S^{\otimes n}||_{\mathrm{op}} \leq \epsilon$ for all $n \in \Omega$ and $\epsilon > 0$ sufficiently small, is it the case that $U = S$? Or is it the case that no matter how small an $\epsilon$ I choose, $U$ need not equal $S$?

I'm not exactly sure how to proceed. Of course I know $||U^{\otimes n} - S^{\otimes n} ||_{\mathrm{op}} \leq n ||U - S||_{\mathrm{op}}$, but this doesn't seem to help. One way might be to provide a nontrivial *lower bound* on $|| U^{\otimes n}-S^{\otimes n}||_{\mathrm{op}}$ in terms of $|| U-S||_{\mathrm{op}}$, but I also don't see how this can be done.

Comment: This is certainly not true for all $\epsilon>0$ because trivially $\lVert U^{\otimes n}-S^{\otimes n}\rVert\leq \lVert U\rVert^n+\lVert S\rVert^n\leq 2$. Or are you interested in an answer depending on $\epsilon$ (i.e what is the range of $\epsilon$ for which this is true)?

Comment: Yes, sorry if that's not clear. If I fix $\epsilon > 0$ sufficiently small, does $||U^{\otimes n} - S^{\otimes n}|| \leq \epsilon$ imply $U = S$? Or is it the case that no matter how small an $\epsilon$ I choose, $U$ need not equal $S$?